# mvc3 Path.GetExtension issue when uploading file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, imageresizer

I am getting an **The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open** error issue when uploading a file been stumped on this for a few days and have isolated the issue.. this code doesn't work

```
var fileName = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);


                                var changename = profile.registrationID+ fileName;
                                var mytrail = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/profilepic"), changename);
                                file.SaveAs(mytrail);
                                ImageBuilder.Current.Build(mytrail, mytrail, new ResizeSettings("width=100&height=130&mode=stretch"));
                                ModelState.Clear();
                                db.Entry(profile).State = EntityState.Modified;
                                db.SaveChanges();
                                return View(profile);
```

when i tried to upload a picture i get the **user-mapped section open error** and the **ImageBuilder.Current.Build(mytrail, mytrail, new ResizeSettings("width=100&height=130&mode=stretch"));** is highlighted . The thing is that in the above code if I change fileName to

```
var fileName = "abc";
```

the whole code works picture gets uploaded with no error only thing is that the picture gets saved as a File instead of a .jpg or .gif.  What about these 2 lines can possibly be causing the error...

```
 var fileName = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                                ImageBuilder.Current.Build(mytrail, mytrail, new ResizeSettings("width=100&height=130&mode=stretch"));
```

This is the imageResizer from http://imageresizing.net/docs/managed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's [easier than that](http://imageresizing.net/docs/howto/upload-and-resize).

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, 
   "~/uploads/profilepic/" + profile.registrationID + ".<ext>", 
    new ResizeSettings("width=100&height=130&mode=stretch"));
```

The more you let ImageResizer do, that faster and safer the job wil be done. Your previous code allowed for any extension file to be uploaded - a big potential exploit opportunity. <ext> only allows image extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the imagebuider is being used incorrectly. I'm unfarmiliar enough with the way its being used directly from a disk location. I'd try to use it directly with file streams, ie.

```
   var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
   var fileName = profile.registrationID+ fileExtension;
   var filePathAndName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/profilepic"), fileName );

   using(var outStream = new MemoryStream()){
     ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file.InputStream, outStream, new ResizeSettings("width=100&height=130&mode=stretch"));
     FileStream file = new FileStream(filePathAndName, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
     byte[] bytes = new byte[outStream.Length];
     outStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)outStream.Length);
     file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     file.Close();
   }
```

please note this code is untested